# Should I stagger a large number of image load calls?

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have a ListView with ~100 large images.  Each image is about 640.640 jpg and is shown 1/2 screen size.  Typical gallery.

I am currently loading the images using the wonderful universal-image-loader-1.9.2.

```
ParseFile photoFile = p.getParseFile("imageFile");
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.displayImage( photoFile.getUrl(), theImageView );
```

Now, you get a bit of stutter on the ListView, when they are loading.

Now, coincidentally, **I had the phone on a very slow WiFi network. IN FACT, IT WAS SMOOTH AS SILK.**

At first, I couldn't work out why the sudden improvement! Serendipity!

In fact then, in that situation: is it worth staggering the calls to load the images?

So, I could leave 0.1" between each call, for example.

Or indeed, should I just do them one follows the other maybe?!

What's the deal there? **Do all android engineers do this all the time?**  Cheers!

I've already applied all the other classical techniques I have googled up for buttery smooth ListView scrolling.  Cheers

(Note that I have tried a number of systems to load the images, doesn't make a difference, it's not an issue with Universal Image Loader, which rocks.)

---

ashishduh, here's the code from getView ... as you see, it's trivial.

(note - setting the size makes no difference. if i try it with say 500.500 fixed, it's the same)

```
...
v.someTextView.setText(blah);
v.someTextView.setText(blah);

// and now the big image
if (p.containsKey("imageFile"))
    {
    // this cell has a big image

    v.mainImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ParseFile photoFile = p.getParseFile("imageFile");

    // ...using p.getNumber("imageWidth").floatValue(); and height
    // from the cloud, calculate needed width/height on the phone...

    v.mainImage.getLayoutParams().width = Math.round(desiredGlassWidth);
    v.mainImage.getLayoutParams().height = Math.round(desiredGlassHeight);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage( photoFile.getUrl(), v.mainImage );
    }
else
    {
    // this pcell has no big image
    v.mainImageIV.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
...
```

Comment: "Now, you get a bit of stutter on the ListView, when they are loading" -- use Traceview to figure out precisely where your problem lies.

Comment: you can use this libs to async load or download file , it's very helpful for performance view
https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading

Comment: wSakly - also an incredible tip. (Should be an answer?)  Universal Image Loader is AMAZING AND AWESOME.  But  I notice the package you reference claims **Avoid Duplicated Simultaneous Fetches**  If so, perhaps that's it.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with UIL but if it's truly asynchronous loading, there should be 0 stutter.  I use a similar library called [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) with a gridview of hundreds of images and there is no stutter.  Maybe post your adapter `getView` code?

Comment: I'll throw in my 2 cents: For an Image gallery, I'd use something like [CoverFlow](https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/). Obvoiusly, this doesn't really answer your question. But maybe this concept would give you a different approach: in one word, ladies and gentlemen... **pagination**! In other words, imagine you load your images 10 at a time. I guess it would be fast enough. Then, by pressing a button (because you designed your ListView to have a Footer, did you?), load the next 10. And the next 10... again and again (what a poet!).

Comment: But this picasso seems to be absolutely fantastic! Better try this one, first. Thank you, @ashishduh, for sharing. +1!

Comment: I also didn'try using it, but it gives me the feeling I NEED to use it in some project... ;)

Comment: Now, since my comment about pagination has become obsolete, I think I'll remove it and go for some meditation on the Shame Hill... ;)

Comment: @ashishduh .. I included the code.  DerGol -- heheh !  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record for anyone googling here ...

I just tried **Picasso** ... per the suggestion in the comment (thanks)

Really, it's fantastic.  Only Volley would be better.

Picasso works so well, my question about staggering image calls is pointless.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Hope it helps someone!

Any better answers, post 'em here for points!

---

PS1 an important point is that Picasso has a "fetch" command, which is a pre-warm.  You can use this for even greater results, in some case.

PS2 as I mention above, the plain fact is the only thing better than Picasso, is moving to Volley. Hope it helps someone.